# Leibnitz notation question

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Leibnitz notation question]

It is incorrect to cancel one of the dx's? If so why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please use mathJax instead of posting pictures. And the chain rule(or method of substitution) implies it is valid to "cancel one of the dx"

Comment: The full operator that you cancel via the Fundamental Theorem of Infinitesimal Calculus is $\frac{d}{dx}$. So what remains is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with the amount of "$d$" balancing in the differential quotient. // "Leibnitz" is, while sometimes occurring not only as a biscuit trademark, not the current standard lettering for "Godefrey Guillaume Leibnitius".

Comment: Probably *Leibniz* was his name first, then he wrote in Latin using *Leibnitius*.  I think, in German, the *t* should not be in there: *Leibniz*, not *Leibnitz*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **second derivative** of $y$ with respect to $x$ is written
$$
\frac{d^2\,y}{dx^2}
$$
That is just notation, so do not try to use it piece by piece.  The logic for the notation is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx}\;y .
$$

---

I don't recommend it (because it is confusing), but if you really want to "cancel" as suggested, it would be: cancel the **first** $dx$
$$
\int \frac{d^2\,y}{dx^2}\;dx = \int d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)
= \frac{dy}{dx} + C
$$